# WooCommerce - changing short description for summary description

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to use woocommerce_single_product_summary instead of woocommerce_short_description.

How to do that? If I just change "woocommerce_short_description", it still shows short description.

Thank you

```
<?php break;
   case 'description': ?>
      <div class="wcpc-compare-row">
         <div class="wcpc-compare-cell" data-compare="<?php echo $k; ?>">
            <div class="wcpc-compare-description">
               <?php $post = get_post($product->get_id()); echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt ); ?>
            </div>
         </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: I think you might be confusing your hooks here. `woocommerce_single_product_summary` is an action, not a filter. It's used to add stuff to the single product page. `woocommerce_short_description` is a filter which is used to alter the product excerpt (ie, short description) on the product page. The code snippet you supplied is using it correctly. In any case, you are passing in the product's excerpt (`$post->post_excerpt`) to the filter, so that is what you will get returned.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get the product description instead of short description you need to use the following:

```
$post->post_content;
```

**instead of :**

```
$post->post_excerpt;
```